# Altering the contents of a column in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I exported data from an excel file. From that file, I have a column called 'ID'.For now that column has entries like the following.

```
ID
1.14455,

2.48755,

3.65588,

4.25415,
```

and so on.

I need to get rid of that comma from the column. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other commas in the values, then just use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, ',', '')
```

If there are possibly other commas:

```
select (case when col like '%,' then left(col, len(col) - 1)
             else col
        end)
```